# Showing that a collection generating a topology is a local basis at 0

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a vector space. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a collection of subsets of $X$, such that each $V \in \mathcal{A}$ contains $0$. Then define $\mathcal{B}$ as the set of finite intersections of sets in $\mathcal{A}$. Let then $\mathcal{C}$ be the set of all translations of sets in $\mathcal{B}$.

I have managed to show that $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis, and it thus generates a topology (the one for which the open sets correspond to arbitrary unions of sets in $\mathcal{C}$). I wish to show then that $\mathcal{B}$ is a local basis of $0$ of this topology, i.e. that for any open set $V$ such that $0 \in V$ there exists $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $B \subset V$.

My progress so far:
Let $U$ be an open set such that $0 \in U$. Then $U = \cup_{\alpha \in I} (x_{\alpha}+B_{\alpha})$ and thus $0 \in x_{\alpha} + B_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha \in I$. But how do we ensure that any of the $B_{\alpha}$ stay inside $U$? Since $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis, we have that $(x_{\alpha}+B_{\alpha}) \cap B_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{C}$, but I do not see how this helps.

Any help is appreciated, and its related to theorem 1.37 of Rudins Functional Analysis

Comment: I think you're missing conditions. It's not true that $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis. For instance, let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and let $\mathcal{A}$ be the collection containing only the interval $[0,1]$. Then $\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{A}$ and the set of translations of $[0,1]$ is not a basis.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now. I looked at my proof of it being a basis and found the mistake after seeing your comment.